# How to add one listener for all events?

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener

`EventDispatcher.addEventListener()` expects first parameter for event type (parameter of String type).

But the current object can generate multiple types of events.

Is it possible to handle all of them in one handler? May be I can pass `null` for type parameter or something?

Comment: No, addEventListener is used to add a single handler to a type, you can call it multiple times for different types and give it the same handler but why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to learn what events when generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to make way around and extend dispatchEvent function :

```
public override function dispatchEvent(evt:Event):Boolean {
     trace(evt.type);
     return super.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

You can put Your code here to handle all events dispatched in this object .

Comment: I think this is a better option than the other proposal because not all Events will be within the Event class definitions many events are defined as sub-classes of Event, this work-around of overriding dispatch event within a sub-class or monkey patched version of the object your interested in the events on would work well.

Comment: And it's very easy to implement .

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, this is possible**.

If you use `getQualifiedClassName` of the Event class, you could get the types using `describeType`. Then you know all types that could be added, assuming you are using a custom event with public static types as strings in same event class. Then you could loop through all types, and add listeners with all those types to the dispatcher.

This idea is included in the [templelibrary](http://templelibrary.googlecode.com) (`EventUtils.addAll`), which I suggest to use.

*See documentation:* http://templelibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/temple/utils/types/EventUtils.html